# Can you use a noun + the possessive marker ('s) in the expression 'to make someone's day"?

Tags: idioms, usage, idiomatic-language

Can you use a noun + the possessive marker ('s) in the expression 'to make someone's day"? Looking up the dictionary, it seems that the expression is only used with possessive pronouns "his", "her", "your", etc., but not nouns accompanied with the possessive marker. Is it possible to do so?

For example:

> Finding the solution to an old mathematics problem made the
>   mathematicians' day.
>
> Finding the solution to an old physics problem made physicists' day.
>
> Giving them flowers made the ladies' day.
>
> Giving her flower made the lady's day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. “His,” “her,” and “your” are all possessive pronouns, but replacing the pronoun with the explicit noun works just as fine. Your first three examples though must be referring to multiple mathematicians, physicists, and ladies (but I believe you know this).